# How to change font size in Eclipse for Java text editors?

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts, font-size

I have just tried to change my font size in Eclipse 3.6.0 in the following way:

> General → Appearance → Colors and Fonts → Java Editor text font

However, the font size only changed in the file I had open. How can I change the font size for all Java files and projects I open in Eclipse?

Comment: Works fine in 3.5 using those same directions.

Comment: FYI, if you want to change all editors at the same time, select General → Appearance → Colors and Fonts → Basic → Text Font.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change font size quickly in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948374/how-to-change-font-size-quickly-in-eclipse)

Comment: Other solution Windows -> Preferences -> General -> appareance -> Colors a fonts -> Structured Text Editor -> Edit. this work for me :)

Comment: Not sure if this is because changes were made beforehand, but I had to make changes to both "Basic" and "Java". The former affected things like the JSP editor, the latter affected the java programming window

Comment: **Eclipse Neon (4.6)** added `Ctrl` + `+` and `Ctrl` + `=` for **Zoom In** and `Ctrl` + `-` for **Zoom Out**. See http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/M4/

Comment: Related (changing ***colours***): *[Eclipse fonts and background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186118)*

Comment: you can simply press   CTR+ to increase and CTR- to decrease

Answer (score 467):

If you are changing the font size, but it is only working for the currently open file, then I suspect that you are changing the wrong preferences.

- On the Eclipse toolbar, select *Window* → *Preferences*
- Set the font size, *General* → *Appearance* → *Colors and Fonts* → *Java* → *Java Editor Text Font*).
- Save the preferences.

Check that you do not have per-project preferences. These will override the top-level preferences.

#### Eclipse v4.2 (Juno) note

Per comment below, this has moved to the Eclipse *Preferences* menu (no longer named the *Window* menu).

#### Eclipse v4.3 (Kepler) note

The *Window* menu is live again, that is, menu *Window* → *Preferences*.

#### Eclipse 2021-12 note

Verified that the path described
(*Window → Preferences, General → Appearance → Colors and Fonts → Java → Java Editor Text Font*)
is still correct.

**Note** Be sure to check out the [ChandraBhan Singh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42083500/3798217), it shows the key bindings to change the font size.

Comment: Was searching for the same question tonight and found this...just a quick note: in JUNO they have moved Preferences section under EClise menu...: EClipse->Preferences..... just If I knew Eclipse keeps moving things around so much!

Comment: tested on Version: Indigo Service Release 2 on 12-12-2012 good answer

Comment: Other solution Windows -> Preferences -> General -> appareance -> Colors a fonts -> Structured Text Editor -> Edit. this work for me :)

Comment: Checked on MARS on 12/18/2015 and still works just fine. Thanks man!

Comment: The Window -> Preferences menu is still there in NEON.

Comment: This is still correct in Eclipse v 4.9 (2018)

Answer (score 91):

**For Eclipse Neon**

To Increase
**Ctrl**  **+**

To reduce **Ctrl**  **-**

[image: shortcut for font eclipse]

Comment: For other languaged keyboards (like Hungarian): CTRL SHIFT (+) CTRL SHIFT (-)

Comment: For Mac OsX use CMD key instead of Ctrl

Comment: For me `Ctrl -` to decrease, but `Ctrl Shift +` to increase.

Answer (score 75):

On Mac:

1. Eclipse toolbar Eclipse → *Settings* OR <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (comma)
2. *General* → *Appearance* → *Colors and Fonts* → *Basic* → *Text Font*
3. Apply

Comment: Edit Eclipse toolbar>Window> @BenniMcBeno.

Comment: Open the java file and use `Command` and `+/-` to increase/decrease the font size

Answer (score 60):

This worked for me:

1. On the Eclipse toolbar, select *Window* → *Preferences*.
2. Set the font size (*General* → *Appearance* → *Colors and Fonts* → *Basic* → *Text Font*):

   [image]
3. Save the preferences.

Comment: Yes this is more applicable as it is global settings

Answer (score 33):

```
General → Appearance → Colors and Fonts → Java Editor text font
```

See the image:

[image]

Comment: @SumitSingh How did you achieve this color shema for eclipse? Can you give some explanation or link?

Comment: This is new theme in Luna See: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/06/20/dark-theme-top-eclipse-luna-feature-5/

Answer (score 20):

The [Eclipse-Fonts](https://code.google.com/p/eclipse-fonts/) extension will add toolbar buttons and keyboard shortcuts for changing font size. You can then use [AutoHotkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) to make **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mousewheel** zoom.

Under menu *Help* → *Install New Software...* in the menu, paste the update URL (http://eclipse-fonts.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FontsUpdate/) into the **Works with:** text box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Expand the tree and select *FontsFeature* as in the following image:

[image: Eclipse extension installation screen capture]

Complete the installation and restart Eclipse. Then you should see the **A** toolbar buttons (circled in red in the following image) and be able to use the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> to zoom (although you may have to unbind those keys from Eclipse first).

[image: Eclipse screen capture with the font size toolbar buttons circled]

To get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + *mouse wheel* zooming, you can use AutoHotkey with the following script:

```
; Ctrl + mouse wheel zooming in Eclipse.
; Requires Eclipse-Fonts (https://code.google.com/p/eclipse-fonts/).
; Thank you for the unique window class, SWT/Eclipse.
;
#IfWinActive ahk_class SWT_Window0
    ^WheelUp:: Send ^{=}
    ^WheelDown:: Send ^-
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: Project is not active anymore.

Answer (score 19):

If you are using Windows then to increase font size try with

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>

and for decreasing font size you can use

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>

Answer (score 16):

Press **`ctrl`** + **`-`** to decrease, and **`ctrl`** + **`+`** to increase the Font Size.

It's working for me in Eclipse Oxygen.

Answer (score 13):

[image]

Menu *Window* → *Preferences*. *General* → *Appearance* → *Colors and Fonts* → *Basic* → *Text Font*

Comment: Appears to be the same answer as [4539511](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18097855/4539511).

Answer (score 11):

On the Eclipse toolbar, select *Window* → *Preferences*, set the font size (*General* → *Appearance* → *Colors and Fonts* → *Basic* → *Text Font*).

Save the preferences.

Comment: How are preferences saved? Pressing button OK?

Comment: If we're talking about the menu bar, this is the same answer as [4539511](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18097855/4539511).

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look at [Eclipse color theme](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/), also which has a hell of a lot of options for customizing font, background color, etc.

Answer (score 4):

1. On the menu bar, select *Window* → *Preferences*
2. Set the font size (*General* → *Appearance* → *Colors and Fonts* → *Structured Text Editors* → *Structured Text Editor Text Font (set to default: Text Font)* → <kbd>Edit...</kbd>).
3. Save the preferences.

Comment: After *Colors and Fonts*, isn't it something like *Java* → *Editor* → *Java Editor Text Font (set to default: Text Font)* (two more levels interjected)? (Seen in [Eclipse v4.6 (Neon)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases), but for C/C++).

Comment: Does not work for me in Neon.2, at least on the Java file I'm looking at.

Answer (score 3):

Running Eclipse v4.3 (Kepler), the steps outlined by AlvaroCachoperro do the trick for the Java text editor and console window text.

Many of the text font options, including the Java Editor Text Font note, are "set to default: Text Font". The 'default' can be found and configured as follows:

On the Eclipse toolbar, select *Window* → *Preferences*. Drill down to: (*General* → *Appearance* → *Colors and Fonts* → *Basic* → *Text Font*) (at the bottom)

- Click <kbd>Edit</kbd> and select the font, style and size
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd> in the Font dialog
- Click <kbd>Apply</kbd> in the Preferences dialog to check it
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd> in the Preferences dialog to save it

Eclipse will remember your settings for your current workspace.

I teach programming and use the larger font for the students in the back.

Answer (score 1):

I Found the best way to increase Font Size in Eclipse:

Follow this path : Eclipse-Folder\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.100.v20180514-1547\css

--There are a bunch of Files here and it depends on user system which file to change.

```
* {
  font-size:13;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

you can even change Font Family if you like.

1. For Windows Users add the following piece of css at BOTTOM of these files:
   **File Names:    e4_default_gtk.css & e4_default_win.css**
2. For Mac Users: e4_default_mac.css

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use menu *Windows* → *Preferences* → *General* → *Appearances* → *Colors and Fonts* → *Java Text Editors* → *Change* → *Apply*.

Answer (score 0):

Try the tarlog plugin. You can change the font through Ctrl++ and Ctrl-- commands with it. A very convenient thing.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/tarlog-plugins/downloads

Answer (score 0):

You can use

ctrl and + or - key

Comment: Works for me. Tested with Oxygen on Linux

Answer (score 0):

If you are using STS, then goto STS/Contents/Eclipse directory and open the STS.ini file.

From the STS.ini file, remove the flooring line:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

And restart the STS.