# Change font and font size in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts, font-size

I am using CVS with Eclipse. When I change the font size through *General* → *Appearance* → *Colors and Fonts*, I get changes applied only in my projects, and those changes are not applied to CVS files (which do not belong to my own files, which is connected through Subversion).

How do I apply the font size even, the Subversion files of my Eclipse?

Comment: What do you mean by "CVS files"?

Comment: Are you using CVS or Subversion? They're completely different things.

Comment: am using CVS which is sharing those files connected with my collegues

Comment: Where exactly are your fonts "not applied"? There are quite a number of preferences in "colors and fonts" ... including a category for "CVS". Could you elaborate on the actual font you wish to change?

Comment: I think he expects the source code to contain information about font size like Microsoft Word documents...

Comment: The canonical question is *[How can I change font size in Eclipse for Java text editors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922305)*.

Answer (score 0):

Files that include code do not have any styling attributes, they just store plain text.

So all users have to set the font size themselves.