# How do I change the default font for Python code in Eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

In Eclipse, how can I change default font for Python code in the editor (PyDev plugin)?

I navigate to menu *Window* → *Preference* → *General* → *Appearance* → *Colors & Fonts*, but I don't find which item would affect the Python code font.

Comment: The canonical question is *[How can I change font size in Eclipse for Java text editors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922305)*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As you are using [PyDev](http://pydev.org/), you should have a look at menu *Window* → *Preferences* → *PyDev* → *Editor* ([PyDev Editor Preferences](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_editor_prefs.html)).

Comment: Yes, I use PyDev. I follow your guide and click on link Color & Fonts at the bottom. I lead me to item Basic - Text Font in screen Colors & Fonts I mentioned in question. That is the item affecting python code fonts. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is for Mac:

Go to Eclipse → *Preferences* → *General* → *Appearance* → *Colors and Fonts* → *Basic* → *Text Font*.

Edit the font structure for the text font.

[Screen shot for the process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osDtn.png)

Answer (score 2):

Following the guidance of **gecco**, I found out the item in *General* → *Appearance* → *Colors & Fonts* which affects Python code fonts. It's *Text Font* in the *Basic* folder.

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac, I can get to the PyDev settings via:

Eclipse → *Preferences* → *PyDev* (in tree) → *Editor* (subtree)

In my case, I wanted to change hash tag comments from nearly invisible grey to a better color. It worked like a charm.