# Change all font sizes in Eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, ide

Is there a way to change all fonts at once in Eclipse?

I have a very large monitor, so my system fonts are quite small (40" screen, size 4 pt on it looks like size 16 on a 19" screen).

The problem is that on my Linux box, Eclipse's fonts are all huge. I changed the key ones (console font, system dialog font), but there are the odd occasions where I have a dialog box or open a certain type of file and the fonts are huge.

Is there a way to set all fonts to a specific size in Eclipse?

Comment: The canonical question is *[How can I change font size in Eclipse for Java text editors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922305)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a post about doing it for the Java editor here: [How can I change font size in Eclipse for Java text editors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922305/how-can-i-change-font-size-in-eclipse-for-java-text-editors)

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts -> Text Font seems to work for me for all all the files I open/write (I'm using Indigo on Fedora).