# How can I change the font of layout (XML) editor in Eclipse?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xml-editor

I know how to change the font of "Java editor" in Eclipse in menu *Windows* → *Preferences* → *Appearance* → *Colors and Fonts*, but I could not find an option for changing the font of "layout editor" for files like myLayout.xml or strings.xml.

Where is it?

Comment: tell me when you discover it..

Comment: See [this](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp) It may helps you.

Comment: Are you talking about Android? What's this layout editor you're talking about. Please go into more detail.

Comment: The canonical question is *[How can I change font size in Eclipse for Java text editors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922305)* (but this does not necessarily make this a duplicate).

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Use menu `Windows` → `Preferences` → `Appearance` → `Colors and Fonts` → `Basic` → `Text Font`. This is a common text font setting that is applied to XML file editors by default.

I also found [this message](http://www.myeclipseide.com/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=10865&start=0&postdays=0&postorder=asc&highlight=).

Comment: Does not it affect on other Appearances?

Comment: Yes it does affect all editors which don't have own settings.

Comment: See edit to my answer, there are more such messages in google

Comment: First click apply button and then click ok button. Otherwise it dose not take affect.

Answer (score 8):

For my Eclipse v4.4 (Luna) installation, the XML editor font size is changed under:

Menu *Window* → *Preferences* → *General* → *Appearance* → *Colors and Fonts* → *Structured Text Editors* → *Structured Text Editor Text Font*.

Comment: This is the correct answer. `Structured Text Editor Text Font` is used by the XML editor. (By default it is set to the basic `Text Font`.)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work in Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers for Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)

Answer (score 2):

I had to expand General to get to Appearance... I figured it out in about 3.2 seconds, but just in case anyone wants to save that 3.2 seconds:

**Windows-> General -> Preferences-> Appearance-> Colors and Fonts-> Basic -> TextFont -> Edit...**

This is in Eclipse IDE for Android Developers v23.0.2.  I'm pretty sure this changes all font sizes for everything in the editor.. ?  But I'm assuming if you want XML font to be bigger, you want all files to be that font size.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to set bold font for XML attribute values in XML editor. It is in Window -> Preferences -> XML -> XML Files -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring.