# How do I change all font sizes in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Regarding Stack Overflow question *[How can I change font size in Eclipse for Java text editors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922305)*:

This question asks how to change the font size in an editor window. But is there a way to change all the font sizes for the entire Eclipse GUI?

Comment: Why? ... However I don't thinks so. But eclipse is open source so you could rebuild it with your font... If you really need it

Comment: I got a monitor for my macbook, so I want the fonts to look bigger on the monitor.

Comment: The eclipse UI is so terrible/ancient. The fact that questions like this have to be asked in the first place are a clear indicator this IDE could use some upgrades.

Answer (score 11):

Go to Window->Preferences,  General->Appearance->Colors and Fonts

Go to basic. Look for *text font* and *text editor*.

Comment: That is not working. Eclipse has some stupid way of UI configuration, and the answer is, that without rebuild from sources there is no nice way of change fonts in all eclipse views.

Answer (score 1):

To change fonts in the Eclipse workspace with Linux, [Ubuntu 10.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_10.04_LTS_.28Lucid_Lynx.29) (Lucid Lynx), I modified system fonts desktop → *System* → *Preferences* → *Appearance* → *Fonts*.

I also modified Eclipse v3.7 (Indigo) → menu *Windows* → *Preferences* → *General* → *Appearances* → *Colors and Fonts*.
It reflected in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

To change eclipse package explorer font size on windows 7

Open below file location where your eclipse exe file is present

```
eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.0.1.v20141126-1957\css/e4_default_win7.css
```

add

```
 .MPart Tree{  
  font-size: 12;  
 }
```

Restart the eclipse for the changes to reflect

Answer (score 0):

Add to `Eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.themes_<version>\css\dark\e4-dark_globalstyle.css`:

```
 * {
    font-size: 13;
}
```

Depending on the Eclipse version and theme (I'm using dark theme!) you are using, you might need to add this to another css file, e.g. `e4_basestyle.css`.