# How do I change the font size in StatET?

Tags: eclipse, statet

I know that this is how to change the font size for editing Java files in Eclipse:

1. Open the Preferences
2. General → Appearance → Colors and Fonts → Java Editor text font
3. Select desired font size

How do I change the font size for editing R files in Eclipse using the StatET plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Philip Murray's comment to [How can I change font size in Eclipse for Java text editors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922305/how-can-i-change-font-size-in-eclipse-for-java-text-editors) one way to do this is to change all editors at the same time:

1. Open the Eclipse Preferences
2. Select General → Appearance → Colors and Fonts → Basic → Text Font
3. Select desired font size