# Tiny text bug on Mavericks eclipses (eclipsii?)

Tags: eclipse, fonts, osx-mavericks

Just got a new MBP, not upgraded from a previous version, and trying to get through a few issues with the new OS and programs.

One oddity that I'm having is with eclipse, in some of the menus, the Variables/Expressions window and the console, some times.  I've included screenshots of it occurring in the debug windows and menu, wasn't able to catch it in the console as that's the inconsistent one.  What occurs there is it looks fairly normal, all ok, but when I bring focus to it, it goes all weird,

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got it after playing around with the colours and fonts, as described [How can I change font size in Eclipse for Java text editors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922305/how-can-i-change-font-size-in-eclipse-for-java-text-editors?rq=1)

Something's definitely messed around because while most things were set right, at 11 or so, they were displaying at 5.  When I then explicitly set them to 11 and restarted, they came back huge.  Then resetting them put everything back to normal.  *shrug*