# How to make all fonts bold in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, customization

Is it possible to make all fonts bold in Eclipse (text editor, menu, variables, all languages)? I see it is possible to change custom style for every language but it takes quite a lot time. Is it possible to somehow use some default bold fonts in everything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change font size in Eclipse for Java text editors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922305/how-can-i-change-font-size-in-eclipse-for-java-text-editors)

Answer (score 3):

Go to `General -> Appereance -> Colors and Fonts`
Then go to `Basic` and try editing fonts here. this will take effect for all type of files. Java, XML etc... Screenshot here is from Eclipse Kepler.

[image]