# Keyboard shortcut to change font size in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, fonts, font-size

It is relatively straightforward to change font sizes in Eclipse through preferences (and answered several times in this forum).

However I'd like to change font size quickly (e.g., with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> like in Linux terminal or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>mouse wheel</kbd> in MS Office apps).  Is there a way to do this in Eclipse?

Comment: I have looked for this too, but to my knowledge there is no such shortcut. The only way to change the font size is via the preferences.

Comment: Related, but sadly also unanswered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790720/eclipse-ide-how-to-zoom-in-on-text

Comment: About CTRL+wheel, there is a [bug submitted to Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=84776) but I see no one working on that; about CTRL++, CTRL+- I see the entries "Zoom in" and "Zoom out" in Eclipse Indigo's `Window > Preferences > General > Keys`, assigned to CTRL+- and CTRL+=, but I can't make them work...

Comment: Other solution Windows -> Preferences -> General -> appareance -> Colors a fonts -> Structured Text Editor -> Edit. this work for me :)

Answer (score 65):

### Eclipse Neon (4.6)

#### Zoom In

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>

or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>

#### Zoom Out

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>

This feature is described [here](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/M4/):

> In text editors, you can now use **Zoom In (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>)** and **Zoom Out (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>)** commands to increase and decrease the font size.
>   Like a change in the General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts preference page, the commands **persistently change the font size in all editors of the same type**. If the editor type's font is configured to use a default font, then that default font will be zoomed.

So, the font size change is not limited to the current file and the new value of the font size is available here **Window** > **Preferences** > **General** > **Appearance** > **Colors and Fonts**.

Comment: Note that you have to use the standard `-` and `+` keys on the keyboard, not the numpad keys. _Ctrl+Numpad_Subtract_ and _Ctrl+Numpad_Add_ are mapped to collapse/expand by default.

Comment: This works but is limiting because there is a big step change between each size of font in the usual viewing zoom level. CTRL + WHEEL on browsers  gives 10% changes which is nicer. I guess it's another idea for the next version of Eclipse . . .

Comment: A good step forward for eclipse, but seems to zoom in or out too much for my eyes. Should lower the 'jump' for each zooms.

Answer (score 54):

I know it has been long since the original question was posted, but for future reference:
check this project, https://github.com/gkorland/Eclipse-Fonts
I have used it, and it's very simple and efficient.

Comment: This worked for me on some files but not on the ones I cared about: .scala and .java files.  The problem turned out to be that eclipse-fonts appears to affect only the "Text Font" setting rather than being aware of the font setting used in the current window.  If you have changed the "Java Editor Text Font" settings away from the default (which is to just use the "Text Font" settings), eclipse-fonts won't work.  The solution is to select "Java Editor Text Font" in "Preferences / General / Appearance / Colors and Fonts" and press Reset.

Comment: Works great for my simple use case (most fonts defaulting to the "Text Font" setting) on Juno on Mac. :)

Comment: Works fine with Eclipse Juno, along with [Color Themes](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/)

Comment: Sidebar buttons are ugly on os x version, but shortcuts work great so that's awesome :) Most popular answer here did not work for me so here goes my upvote.

Comment: Works great, Juno on OS X 10.9, JDK 7u25 here.  The best part is you don't need to close/reopen the file editor for changes to take effect.

Comment: I just tried this on Kepler, and it didn't seem to work.  But tarlog 1.4.2 did work (in dropins/).

Comment: Works with Luna, but only with the menu buttons, not with ctrl+/-

Comment: xkr47 has forked the original plugin on github and updated it to a working version with Eclipse Luna. URL to the working version is updated.
In regards to the ctrl +/-; make sure to use the '+' and '-' found at the top of the keyboard. They don't work with +/- next found on numpad.

Comment: @MohamedEl-Beltagy The link still points to Google Code, rather than xkr47's GitHub repo. Is this intentional?

Comment: @EngineerBetter I'm not sure why the link is not updated. But any way, the fork is here: https://github.com/xkr47/Eclipse-Fonts

Comment: Neon has Ctrl +/- to zoom font size by default (no plugin needed)

Answer (score 50):

Take a look at this project: http://code.google.com/p/tarlog-plugins/downloads/detail?name=tarlog.eclipse.plugins_1.4.2.jar&can=2&q=

It has some other features, but most importantly, it has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to change the font size, it's awesome.

Comment: hey marcel can u give some link or documentation abt it? i need some more info abt this.

Comment: Well other than this post http://tarlogonjava.blogspot.com/2008/07/open-command-prompt-or-windows-explorer.html at the creator's website there isn't much. But if you're wondering how to install it, just copy the jar to you eclipse/plugins/ directory and restart eclipse, you should be able to do ctrl++ and ctrl+- to change font size then

Comment: Great, thanks for sharing. To install the plugin, all you have to do in Eclipse 3.7 is to copy the JAR into `/eclipse/dropins`.

Comment: @RAS You can always ask, if you need to know more :) All posts about this plugin can be found by http://tarlogonjava.blogspot.com/search/label/tarlog-plugins

Comment: @MarcelValdezOrozco, this is working for me in 4.2.1 as of 1/15/13, so I think its still working with new versions.

Comment: I want to use this plugin, but I don't seem to have a plugins or dropins directory in eclipse/: anyone know where to put the file/how to use it?

Comment: Works for me, but only if I put it in plugins/ not in dropins/ - whatever the difference is, it matters.  This on a Linux machine, and Eclipse updated itself earlier today.

Comment: It should be `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `+` for zoom

Comment: New location for tool is https://github.com/tarlog/tarlog-plugins/releases and doc is at http://tarlogonjava.blogspot.com/search/label/tarlog-plugins

Comment: @DarenW Works on Eclipse Mars, Linux when putting it into /dropins. Using the 1.4.2 jar from Github.

Answer (score 29):

The [Eclipse-Fonts](https://code.google.com/p/eclipse-fonts/) extension will add toolbar buttons and keyboard shortcuts for changing font size. You can then use AutoHotkey to make **Ctrl+Mousewheel** zoom.

Under **Help | Install New Software...** in the menu, paste the update URL (http://eclipse-fonts.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FontsUpdate/) into the **Works with:** text box and press **Enter**. Expand the tree and select **FontsFeature** as in the following image:

[image: Eclipse extension installation screen capture]

Complete the installation and restart Eclipse, then you should see the **A** toolbar buttons (circled in red in the following image) and be able to use the keyboard shortcuts **Ctrl+-** and **Ctrl+=** to zoom (although you may have to unbind those keys from Eclipse first).

[image: Eclipse screen capture with the font size toolbar buttons circled]

To get **Ctrl+MouseWheel** zooming, you can use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) with the following script:

```
; Ctrl+MouseWheel zooming in Eclipse.
; Requires Eclipse-Fonts (https://code.google.com/p/eclipse-fonts/).
; Thank you for the unique window class, SWT/Eclipse.
#IfWinActive ahk_class SWT_Window0
    ^WheelUp:: Send ^{=}
    ^WheelDown:: Send ^-
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: I'm using luna 4.4.1. I installed it but the buttons don't work. I've bound the keys and tried them but still didn't work. I'm writing this just to let you know as I've managed to install tarlog's plug in successfully

Comment: also I had to change the {=} into {+} for it to work.

Answer (score 15):

Windows > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts

Then, to change Java editor font: Java > Java Editor Text Font > EDIT

There it is.

Comment: since he writes **It is relatively straightforward to change font sizes in Eclipse through preferences** this solution is explicitly **not** requested. -1!

Comment: Also I do not seek so many short-cuts in such kind of IDE. Otherwise I prefer to go to vim :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, eclipse doesn't have any feature `font size` for `PyDev`

Answer (score 10):

Oddly, working on a .js file and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>+=</kbd> works to zoom in (and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> works to zoom out but you have to select <kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>2</kbd> after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>).  This only works when I'm in the js file but the zoom applies to all my open tabs.  Using Eclipse Juno on Ubuntu.

Comment: You’re not using the Aptana plugins by any chance, are you?

Answer (score 9):

In Eclipse Neon.3, as well as in the new Eclipse Photon (4.8.0), I can resize the font easily with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd>, without any plugin or special key binding.

At least in Editor Windows (this does not work in other Views like Console, Project Explorer etc).

Answer (score 4):

Found a great plugin that works in Juno and Kepler.  It puts shortcuts on the quick access bar for increasing or decreasing text size.

Install New Software -> http://eclipse-fonts.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FontsUpdate/

Answer (score 0):

I use an Eclipse plugin (in Eclipse Marketplace)
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/fontsize

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quicker way than multi-layer menus without resorting to plug-ins:

Use the Quick Access tool at the upper left corner.

Type in "font", then, from the list that drops down, click on the link for "Preferences->Colors and Fonts->General->Appearance".

One click replaces the 4 needed to get there through menus. I do it so often, my Quick Access tool pulls it up as a previous choice right at the top of the list so I can just type "font" with a tap on the enter key and Boom!, I'm there.

If you want a keyboard shortcut, Ctrl+3 sets the focus to the Quick Access tool. Better yet, this even automatically brings up a list with your previous choices. The last one you chose will be on top, in which case a simple Ctrl+3 followed by enter would bring you straight there! I use this all the time to make it bigger during long typing or reading sessions to ease eye strain, or to make it smaller if I need more text on the screen at one time to make it easier to find something.

It's not quite as nice as zooming with the scroll wheel or with a simple Ctrl+ or Ctrl-, but it's a lot better than navigating through the menus every time!