# Eclipse Shortcut Key for Color and Fonts -> Basic -> Text Font

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I often change the font size of my editor. So does anyone know a shortcut key for that? Until now I have to use the menu with several clicks: Preferences -> Color and Fonts -> Basic -> Text Font. Would be nice of one can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + MouseWheel...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard shortcut to change font size in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948374/keyboard-shortcut-to-change-font-size-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am sure at some point of time you would have wanted to increase/decrease the font using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> or mouse scroll.
Found one solution, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>+/-</kbd> keys for increasing and decreasing font.

- Download jar from 
  http://code.google.com/p/tarlog-plugins/downloads/list
- Place the jar in plugins directory of eclipse installation
- Restart eclipse.

Enjoy

Answer (score 3):

You can *get close* by binding your-favorite-function-key to the command.  Here's how:

- Windows > Preferences > General > Keys
- Locate the command related to setting the font >> Preferences (General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts)
- Click inside the **Binding** text field
- Specify the key-binding you wish to use by pressing the appropriate keys
- Accept by pressing **OK**
- Profit!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Aptana with an English keyboard and casually came into these keys combinations
- [CTRL] + [-]  then  1   --> smaller font
- [CTRL] + [SHIFT] + [=] --> bigger font

NOTE:
[-] key is on the main keyboard, not the numeric pad
[SHIFT] + [=]  gives + in the English keyboard