# How to increase generic font size in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-juno

Actually I want to increase font size in eclipse of my editor but the post which I found this two post on stackoverflow [Post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922305/how-can-i-change-font-size-in-eclipse-for-java-text-editors), [Post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948374/how-to-change-font-size-quickly-in-eclipse)

First of all some of the good answers are saying that Goto

```
General → Appearance → Colors and Fonts → Java Editor text font
```

But I don't want to increase font size only for java editor but for eack and every editor

Can Someone please tell me how to do it for every editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You go to `General → Appearance → Colors and Fonts → Basic`

Select **Text Font** and increase to whatever value you want it to be.

[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

`General → Appearance → Colors and Fonts → Java Editor text font`

When you click on it, to the right side, Edit Default button is enabled. Click on it to open the dialog box for the default text properties for all editors. Any change you do here is reflected across all the editors; unless, you have manually changed the font property of any editor. By default, all the editors have their values set to the default values. I tried changing the font-size and it reflects across 4 different file types.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to change font size in Eclipse (Juno) is going to 
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts -> Basic -> Text Font.

You will change the font size of all perspectives (Java editor, debug, etc.).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Increase or decrease the font size in Eclipse (STS) IDE Keyboard shortcut:

Increase the font size: press and hold Ctrl button and tap '+' key to increase the font size to the size visible to you.

Decrease the font size: press and hold Ctrl button and tap '-' key to decrease the font size to the size you want.