# How to change the font for the Eclipse Content Assist (Template Proposals) window

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts

I'm working in Eclipse 4.x (Juno).

I just bought a 4k monitor, as millions of programmers are sure to do soon :-).

I'm trying to make Eclipse work with a very dense (high DPI) environment. I've managed to change everything to compensate but the Content Assist window. You can change the colors, but there's no obvious place to change the font.

Is there any way to change this? A config file somewhere? I am on a Mac / OSX.

Comment: try this :- [Change Font](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-20.htm) [change font size in eclipse ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922305/how-can-i-change-font-size-in-eclipse-for-java-text-editors) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948374/how-to-change-font-size-quickly-in-eclipse

Comment: Eclipse bug [44976](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=44976) covers this, but it has been open for 11 years(!) and doesn't look like being fixed any time soon. It might be possible to do with the CSS support (might need the extra CSS support in Eclipse Luna)

Comment: @greg-449 I am using Eclipse Luna and my issue is the size of the content assist size. How can someone accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I figured it out myself.

From the looks of things, these two windows use the System-level settings rather than Eclipse-specific configuration. That means, unfortunately, you can't change it within Eclipse.

For OSX, I used a program called TinkerTool. I changed the setting for "Help Tags", which did the trick.

HOWEVER, this, of course, changes the settings for your whole system, and makes certain windows look weird and wrong.

Hopefully Eclipse will fix this someday, and make that window configurable in Preferences...