# How to change the console font size in Eclipse-PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, fonts

I am trying to use the PyDEV console in eclipse for a demonstration of some Python code. For this demonstration I need to resize the default font size used in the PyDev console window.

Some googling led me to change the  'General/Appearance/Colors and Fonts/Debug/Console Font', but that didn't work. I tried changing all candidates I could identify in the Colors and Font settings, but none of them influences the font size in the PyDev console window.

Is there any way to achieve this?

This is in eclipse 4.3.2 (kepler) with Pydev 3.8

Answer (score 1):

***Solution:***

Help > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors And Fonts > Structed Text Editors > Edit

Comment: Preferences isn't under the Help menu in Eclipse. This should be downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Look in this post: [Keyboard shortcut to change font size in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948374/how-to-change-font-size-quickly-in-eclipse)

It works for Eclipse overall, not just Java or Python. I am using Luna, and ctrl- and ctrl+ do not work, but the "bigger" and "smaller" buttons up top work.

To add this Eclipse plugin, add the following update site via "Install New Software..." under "Help": http://eclipse-fonts.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FontsUpdate/

Maybe a commenter can say if this works on Kepler?

Comment: I tried this, and unfortunately it doesn't work. When I am in the console and I press the "bigger" button in the menu, I see the text in the editor expanding, however the python console stubbornly stays the same size :-(

Comment: For me, the console output also increases in size with the editor text. Are you looking at the console in the Eclipse window, or are you spawning a new and separate console window when your program runs?

Comment: It matters which console you look at: the debug-console or (for instance) the SVN console neatly change their font size. Just the python console doesn't. This console is not associated with any running programs, it's just an independent python shell.