# How to change all of eclipse fonts size's at once?

Tags: eclipse

I understand I can go in and change say the text editors font settings and anything else individually.

In general all of the font is to small for me and i'd rather increase everything from the default 10 to something like 12.  However doing each piece is not only time consuming but annoying.   What i'm wondering is, is there a place I can go to increase all font for everything in eclipse rather than 1 piece at a time?

Comment: How exactly are you changing the font size now?

Comment: Individually Windows>Preferences>General>Appearance>Colors and Fonts then pick category  IE Java>Java Editor Text Font.  However this makes me do them 1 at a time.  I'm looking for a setting that will change all of them at once.

Comment: Perhaps this question could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948374/how-to-change-font-size-quickly-in-eclipse