# Eclipse Fonts Zoom out & Zoom in Issue

Tags: android, eclipse, fonts, eclipse-plugin, eclipselink

How to Zoom in and Zoom out text in Eclipse?
I found plugins but I can not Install Manually
Kindly tell me the procedure to install different Plugins in Eclipse.
I asked this question after facing lot of issue using Android development tools(Eclipse).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse IDE: How to zoom in on text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790720/eclipse-ide-how-to-zoom-in-on-text)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this link and you will love it
[Eclipse-Fonts](https://code.google.com/p/eclipse-fonts/)
First you have to open eclipse, in help Menu, find "Install new Softwares" paste the below link in "Works with" text Box

> http://eclipse-fonts.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FontsUpdate/

and press Enter, in the below box you will see "Eclipse-fonts", now press the next buttons..... and you have done it.
[image]
After installation is finished, you will see **A** icon in toolbox and you can zoom in using **Ctrl+** and Zoom out using **Ctrl-**
[image]

I think this will help you.

Answer (score 5):

Too late but it could be helpful :

Go to `Window Menu > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts`

then go to `Java > Java Editor Text Font > Edit`

Comment: we can not zoom in or zoom out at coding by this method......we will change font size to some value by this method, anyway thanks

Comment: Thhis help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse Neon has a built-in zoom option. The default key binds are:
`Ctrl +` or `Ctrl =` to Zoom in and
`Ctrl -` to zoom out.

Answer (score 2):

I've answered it here. [How can I change font size in Eclipse for Java text editors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922305/how-can-i-change-font-size-in-eclipse-for-java-text-editors/42083500#42083500)

**For Eclipse Neon**

To Increase **Ctrl +**

To reduce **Ctrl -** 
[image]

Comment: Thanks @ChandraBhan