# Are Eclipse Zoom In and Zoom Out native features really working?

Tags: eclipse, zooming

This seems a silly question, but, are *Zoom in* and *Zoom out* of Eclipse (Kepler here) really working?
I tried it in all the ways I think possible, with no success.

When looking at the features descriptions in *Keys*, it's pretty simple: just use *Ctrl+=* and *Ctrl+-*.

Are we forced to use a plugin to have it work? As advised in this post: [eclipse-fonts-zoom-out-zoom-in-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136118/eclipse-fonts-zoom-out-zoom-in-issue) ?

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
After some more investigation, I confirm that this feature, even if present in Eclipse Keys (Preference >> General >> Keys >> Zoom In & Zoom Out), is NOT working. 
This is reported in the following [Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=84776).

So, finally, to have it work, **the use of a plugin is mandatory**.

For Eclipse Kepler, [FontsUpdate](http://eclipse-fonts.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FontsUpdate/) (already spoken about in thread [Keyboard shortcut to change font size in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948374/how-to-change-font-size-quickly-in-eclipse)) is working fine (it enables <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to control the zoom).