# Cannot ZOOM text in Eclipse 4.4.2 LUNA

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to make my Mousewheel + CTRL work as a zoom shortcut. it suddenly stopped working.

I also noticed that (CTRL + =) and (CTRL + -) shortcuts no longer work either.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

I reinstalled eclipse, installed the tarlog plugin etc.. haven't been able to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse IDE: How to zoom in on text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790720/eclipse-ide-how-to-zoom-in-on-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help.

1. Press `Ctrl + Shift + L` twice to get the "Keys" Preferences
2. Type "zoom" in the textbox on the top
3. You will get "Zoom In" and "Zoom Out" commands
4. Check their binding (in my case, it shows `Ctrl + =` for "Zoom In" and `Ctrl + -` for "Zoom Out" options)

Comment: Thats the weird part. I am able to bind them, but it wont work once looking at the source code

Comment: @user3256369 - Have a look at the `.log` file (or `Error Log` view) for any key binding errors.  Also ensure that the `When:` option has `In Windows` in key binding.

Comment: tried it, still no luck. ill keep the log open while coding and let you know if anything pops up

Comment: Is 2016, same issues. Ridiculous that this doesn't just work.

Answer (score -1):

You have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd>