# Eclipse: How to zoom on the text ? It doesn't work for me

Tags: eclipse

I have gone through [Eclipse IDE: How to zoom in on text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790720/eclipse-ide-how-to-zoom-in-on-text) to zoom in or zoom out on a text and now I have it

Eclipse show me the two "A" buttons as shown in attached screenshot

[image]

But when I click on a "A", it does NOT zoom in or zoom out.
I also tried the keyboard shortcuts, but it didn't work. Is it normal ?

Comment: As you are on Mac you may need to remove `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts` from eclipse.ini to enable it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse IDE: How to zoom in on text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790720/eclipse-ide-how-to-zoom-in-on-text)